# Nested route not working in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two routes in App.js

```
<Switch>
    <MainRoute exact={true} path="/" component={Main} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

In Main component I have:

```
<div><Link to="/reviews" /></div>
<div style={{ height: '1000px' }}>
  {/* Routes */}
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/reviews" component={Reviews} />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

The login and Main route work properly and link is displayed. But after clicking on the link, the page becomes blank.

PS: I am a newbie in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your routes like this,

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <MainRoute path="/" component={Main} />
</Switch>
```

First it'll match path `/login` and if it doesn't match it'll match `/`. `/` will match to both `/` and `/reviews`. You need to,

1. remove `exact=true` so that `/` also matches `/reviews`
2. change the order of `/` and `/login`, so that it first tries to match `/login` and then `/`

Comment: Thanks, it worked